# jq: Wrap all first-level atomic values with a list

Tags: json, jq

Suppose we have a JSON:

```json
{
 "a" : 23,
 "b" : "hi",
 "c": [90],
 "d": [{"j" : 80}]
}
```

I want to convert this to

```json
{
 "a" : [23],
 "b" : ["hi"],
 "c": [90],
 "d": [{"j" : 80}]
}
```

How do I do this using `jq`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could update `|=` each field `.[]` using an `if` statement based on the value's `type`:

```bash
.[] |= if type == "array" then . else [.] end
```

```json
{
  "a": [
    23
  ],
  "b": [
    "hi"
  ],
  "c": [
    90
  ],
  "d": [
    {
      "j": 80
    }
  ]
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/_6wXx9Z4hQc)

Instead of checking the `type` against `array`, you could also just update `scalars`, which are all non-iterables, i.e. no arrays and no objects:

```bash
(.[] | scalars) |= [.]
```

```json
{
  "a": [
    23
  ],
  "b": [
    "hi"
  ],
  "c": [
    90
  ],
  "d": [
    {
      "j": 80
    }
  ]
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/UDqIqz8NAQQ)

Answer (score 2):

Please try this:

```
jq 'with_entries(.value|=([.]|flatten))' input.json
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/Sf9uHXDmsez)